# Transform a Sales Order into a Invoice with SuiteTalk

Tags: web-services, netsuite

In NetSuite's SuiteTalk how do I transform a record from a Sales Order to an Invoice?  It looks like there is a function in SuiteScript, but I can't find anything similar in SuiteTalk.

**SuiteScript:**

> **nlapiTransformRecord(type, id, transformType, transformValues)**
>
> Initializes a new record using data from an existing record of a
>   different type and returns an nlobjRecord. This function can be useful
>   for automated order processing such as creating item fulfillment
>   transactions and invoices off of orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuiteTalk has an analogous *initialize* method. With the Java library you'd use it like:

```
        ReadResponse initCS = nsClient.getPort().initialize(new InitializeRecord(InitializeType.cashSale, new InitializeRef(null, InitializeRefType.salesOrder, soId, null), null));

        CashSale cs = (CashSale)initCS.getRecord();
```

Comment: Thanks from me as well. I'm actually working with the PHP library from github but figuring out how to do some of the operations is just a matter of trial and error. I had a devil of a time figuring out cashSale/Invoice until I saw the initialize stuff laid out here.